# Where is the request to the CSS file in the Firefox network inspector? Crazy optimization?

Tags: css, google-chrome, http, firefox, inspector

I'm trying some hack to customize the colors of my Swagger interface (Java / SpringBoot 2.8 project). The hack I tried worked on Google Chrome, but not on Firefox. And the reason it's really weird (at least for me, a humble back-end developer).

By looking to the browser inspector, in the network tab... in Chrome we see, as expected, a request to download the CSS file. But not in Firefox! See the figures.

Firefox:

[image: In Firefox we do not see a request to the CSS file; how is that possible?]

Chrome:

[image: In Chrome we see a request to the CSS file]

How is that possible? How does Firefox download the CSS file (the page is nicely rendered) without a explicit request to it? Some kind of http optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... it was just the browser cache... ¬¬